# Confusion about logic when using strcmp() function

Tags: c, strcmp

```
char string1[10];
char string2[10];

strcpy(string1, "hello");
strcat(string2, string1);

if(strcmp(string1, string2)){
   printf("Heellloww!!!);
} else {
   printf("Bye");
}
```

When I perform check on `if(strcmp(string1, string2))` then what should `strcmp()` return? Should it always return positive 1 in order to execute statements in `if`?

Comment: Your questions are all answerd in the [strcmp man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strcmp). Read that first and come back to ask if there is something you don't understand. BTW, your `strcat` is incorrect. Both parameters need to be valid strings. But `string2` is uninitialised and contains junk.

Comment: Unless your question is about what values are considered "true" in an `if` statement. In which case that is not a `strcmp` question but a basic C question. And the answer would be any value apart from `0` evaluates to true in C.

Comment: Since both string1 and string2 are size 10, then you should check the sizes before issuing the strcat in order to ensure that you do not have overflow. Otherwise, if strlen(string1)+strlen(string2) > 9, then you will get a buffer overflow with the bad results. Of course, this assumes that you have set the values properly earlier in the code (or initialized both to valid strings).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your code is `strcat`: it causes *undefined behavior*.

In order for `strcat` to work, both strings passed to it must be null-terminated. However, the first string that you pass is *not* null-terminated - in fact, it is uninitialized.

Fixing this problem is simple - you can place zero into the initial position of `string2` at declaration:

```
char string2[10] = { 0 };
```

Now the strings would compare as equal, meaning that `strcmp` would return zero. If you want `Heellloww` printed when two strings are the same, you need to add `== 0` to your `if` statement.

Answer (score 3):

Always check the manual:

`int strcmp(const char *s1, const char *s2);`

> Return value:
>   The strcmp() and strncmp() functions return an integer less than, equal to, or greater than zero if s1 (or the first n bytes thereof) is found,  respectively,  to  be less than, to match, or be greater than s2.

In your case, `strcmp` returns zero if `string1` and `string2` are the same (or match). So in case they *are* the same, you would print `Bye`, and if they are different then you would print `Heellloww`.